# Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@1237a068

Tags: java, xml, android-studio

I am working on an Android Studio project. I get an error. The error says that, cannot extract resources from com.android.aaptcompiler.[ParsedResource@1237](mailto:ParsedResource@1237a068)

Build Output

```
> Task :app:mergeDebugResources 
C:\Users\User\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\49dd37bf10937f4a5031c2e2032cd3be\transformed\material-1.4.0\res\values\values.xml:454:4: <item> inner element must either be a resource reference or empty.
```

```
> Task :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.ResourceCompilerRunnable
   > Resource compilation failed (Failed to compile values resource file C:\Users\User\AndroidStudioProjects\Iwant\app\build\intermediates\incremental\debug\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml. Cause: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@270a65c5.). Check logs for more details.
```

Please help me to fix this error.

```
\values.xml:454: 

<item name="material_ic_keyboard_arrow_previous_black_24dp" type="drawable">@drawable/material_ic_keyboard_arrow_left_black_24dp</item>
```